# Backup a running Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker, linux-containers

Is it possible to backup a running Docker container? Is the `export` command suitable for doing that?

Comment: Hi Slava, sorry that your question was closed. For the record, Slava is talking about http://docker.io, a runtime for linux containers.

Yes, 'docker export' is a suitable approach. It will generate a tarball of your entire container filesystem state, and dump it on stdout. So "docker export $CONTAINER_ID > $CONTAINER_ID-backup.tar" will yield a usable tarball.

You can re-import the tarball with "docker import - slava/$CONTAINER_ID-backup < $CONTAINER_ID-backup.tar"

Note the original metadata (eg id of the original image) will be lost.  This should be fixed in future versions of docker.

Comment: @SolomonHykes One more clarification - will it yield a LVM-snapshot-like tarball or just a regular tarball with data changing during the tar?

Comment: Also have a look at https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/2116 , part of the issue is discussed there

Comment: Also take a look at my answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288070/is-it-safe-to-commit-a-running-container-in-docker/27289457#27289457

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Posted by one friend in comments

Hi Slava, sorry that your question was closed. For the record, Slava is talking about docker.io, a runtime for linux containers. Yes, `docker export` is a suitable approach. It will generate a tarball of your entire container filesystem state, and dump it on stdout. So

`docker export $CONTAINER_ID > $CONTAINER_ID-backup.tar`

will yield a usable tarball. You can re-import the tarball with

`docker import - slava/$CONTAINER_ID-backup < $CONTAINER_ID-backup.tar`

Note the original metadata (eg id of the original image) will be lost. This should be fixed in future versions of docker. 
–  **Solomon Hykes Apr 2 '13 at 6:35**

Adding here so one can find from summary that question was answered. Thanks Solomon!

Answer (score 9):

`export` has some limitations: it won't export the *data volume*.

Here's *data volume* means:

1. There's a `VOLUME` defined in the image's Dockerfile.
2. The container is start with a parameter like this: `-v /webapp`

More about data: https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/

The way to handle this situation is start a new container with '**--volumes-from**' parameter to hook on that container, so you can visit the data volume.

Examples:

1. Visit the data: (in a bash)

`docker run -it --volumes-from target_container ubuntu bash`

2. Backup to host: (a postgres container)

`docker run -it --volumes-from some_postgres -v /host/path:/container/path --rm ubuntu bash -c "tar -cvf /container/path/postgres-backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data"`

Answer (score 1):

Using the `docker commit` is my preferred way to back up a container (started or stopped). Creates an image that you can name:

```
docker commit - p <container_id> <backup-name>
```

Answer (score -2):

you can also using save and load.. here's the sample

1. `sudo docker images`

   ```
   awan@google-dev:~/StarCenter/_docker$ sudo docker images
   REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
   google_star/_version_1.10           latest              1067d6689697b2        4 days ago          1.666 GB
   ```
2. `sudo docker save google_star/_version_1.10 > my_docker-backup.tgz`
3. restore it using (`sudo docker load < my_docker-backup.tgz`)
4. check your images using `sudo docker images` in your new docker machine

Comment: I think save/load is about **images**, but the question is about **a running container**.

Comment: I have save/load db image but when I load it, there wasn't any table.