# Can Docker containers (NOT Docker images) be moved?

Tags: docker

I found this information on the [Docker Website](https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/#inside-docker)

> Docker containers can be run, started, stopped, moved, and deleted.

As far as I know, Docker-Images can be moved and Docker-Containers can't. But the information above stands clearly below the headline "Docker containers".

So I would like to know, whether containers could be moved or not (and if not: What is meant with "Docker containers can be moved").

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can save a container with

`docker save` 
see 
https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#save

and restore them otherwhere with

`docker load`
see
https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#load
(it is just a tar file)

but keep in mind this will not save the volumes of the container

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#data-volumes

nor the associated volumes from

https://docs.docker.com/userguide/dockervolumes/#creating-and-mounting-a-data-volume-container

For that there is a project

docker-backup
https://github.com/discordianfish/docker-backup

Comment: This is the answer for moving images, not containers. For containers, see e. g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21323868/586754 .