# How to copy docker volume from one machine to another?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have created a docker volume for postgres on my local machine.

```
docker create volume postgres-data
```

Then I used this volume and run a docker.

```
docker run -it -v postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main postgres
```

After that I did some database operations which got stored automatically in postgres-data. Now I want to copy that volume from my local machine to another remote machine. How to do the same.

**Note - Database size is very large**

Comment: Do you have an overlay network in docker, or swarm mode configured with the two hosts?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27692915/can-docker-containers-not-docker-images-be-moved/27693337#27693337 and the discussion referenced in the comment

Comment: @BMitch - both machines are in LAN.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the second machine has SSH enabled you can use an Alpine container on the first machine to map the volume, bundle it up and send it to the second machine.

That would look like this:

```sh
docker run --rm -v <SOURCE_DATA_VOLUME_NAME>:/from alpine ash -c \
    "cd /from ; tar -cf - . " | \
    ssh <TARGET_HOST> \
    'docker run --rm -i -v <TARGET_DATA_VOLUME_NAME>:/to alpine ash -c "cd /to ; tar -xpvf - "'
```

You will need to change:

- SOURCE_DATA_VOLUME_NAME
- TARGET_HOST
- TARGET_DATA_VOLUME_NAME

Or, you could try using this helper script https://github.com/gdiepen/docker-convenience-scripts

Hope this helps.

Comment: I got one error in cli. In another machine docker is installed with sudo. So I added sudo in your command. `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
write /dev/stdout: broken pipe`

Comment: I resolved the sudo issue. Now I get the error as `tar: short read.
write /dev/stdout: broken pipe`. I tried to run docker on another machine but it does not get the data

Comment: Which method are you using? The single line or the helper script?

Comment: Single line. Issue is resolved now. I copied volume to another machine. Your answer is correct, but data is too large, can we make tar or gzip and transfer ?

Comment: The single line is a tar, if you want to try compressing it then you could try adding in the -z option at other ends, it would look like something along the lines of `docker run --rm -v <SOURCE_DATA_VOLUME_NAME>:/from alpine ash -c "cd /from ; tar -cfz - . " | ssh <TARGET_HOST> 'docker run --rm -i -v <TARGET_DATA_VOLUME_NAME>:/to alpine ash -c "cd /to ; tar -xpvfz - "`

Comment: Thanks it is working perfect. Is there any way to making tar and physically transferring data ? Can you please explain the command ?

Comment: Notice, command in the answer is missing an `'` in the end of the line otherwise it works fine. Ensure that your destination containers are stopped before copying the volume

Comment: syntax for compression should be `tar -czf -` and `tar -xpvzf -` (`-f -` is the final argument)

Answer (score 4):

I had an exact same problem but in my case, both volumes were in separate VPCs and couldn't expose SSH to outside world. I ended up creating [dvsync](https://github.com/suda/dvsync) which uses [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel between them and then use [rsync over SSH](https://rsync.samba.org/) to copy the data. In your case you could start the `dvsync-server` on your machine:

```
$ docker run --rm -e NGROK_AUTHTOKEN="$NGROK_AUTHTOKEN" \
  --mount source=postgres-data,target=/data,readonly \
  quay.io/suda/dvsync-server
```

and then start the `dvsync-client` on the target machine:

```
docker run -e DVSYNC_TOKEN="$DVSYNC_TOKEN" \
  --mount source=MY_TARGET_VOLUME,target=/data \
  quay.io/suda/dvsync-client
```

The `NGROK_AUTHTOKEN` can be found in [ngrok dashboard](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/auth) and the `DVSYNC_TOKEN` is being shown by the `dvsync-server` in its stdout.

Once the synchronization is done, the `dvsync-client` container will stop.