# Copy docker volume to google compute engine instance

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, docker-volume

I have a google compute engine instance (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS).

I want to copy docker volumes from my local machine to the google compute engine instance. I tried to use the command given in - [How to copy docker volume from one machine to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42973347/how-to-copy-docker-volume-from-one-machine-to-another?noredirect=1&lq=1) 
But it didn't work. Please help.

Comment: Your question does not have sufficient information to help you. Please share what steps you tried and how you realized it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Mount the volumes on your local machines, so that data can be accessible as File System level.
Then You need to have 'gcloud' setup properly on your local-machine.

Then you can use gcloud commands to copy the data from local-machine to GCE-Instances.

[Method to copy files from local machine to GCP Instances](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/copy-files)