# Cancel --rm option on running docker container

Tags: docker

I have started a container with the option `--rm`, for example:

```
docker run --rm -it --name test bash
```

But now I want to keep the container on exit. Is there a way to cancel the `--rm` option on an already running container?

Comment: This is not possible, you can try to create an image from this, with commit.

Comment: As it's already been mentioned, unfortunately not possible, however, you should look into mapping a volume into your container so you don't lose your work in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible.

An alternative that might suit you would be to [commit](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) your container as a new image and run that image in a new container.

Comment: Keep in mind that for windows containers you cannot commit a during container : 
`Error response from daemon: windows does not support commit when container is running`
And you also cannot pause the container : `Error response from daemon: Cannot pause container f680327c0109a2895aea681ef59449cd3a620ced0396eb12074195473e543566: cannot pause Windows Server Containers`

Comment: Not great... For this reason and others, I still consider Docker on Windows a hack.

Answer (score 1):

Probably detach and commit the running container is a good choice.

1. detach from the running container: `Ctrl+P`, `Ctrl+Q` (for Ubuntu).
2. commit the running container as a new image.